# SSL exception in JAVA6 but no in JAVA8

Tags: java, rest, ssl, jdk6

Hy

I try to connect a java program to an REST API.

With the same part of code I have a Java Exception in Java 6 and it works fine in Java 8.

It's the same environment :

- trustore
- machine
- unix user

the code :

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main (String[] args){

        String serviceUrl = "https://api.domain.com" + "/endpont/path";
        try {
            URL url = new URL(serviceUrl);
            URLConnection connection = null;
            try{
                connection = url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                String body = "";
                String inputLine;
                DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream (connection.getInputStream());
                while (((inputLine = input.readLine()) != null)){
                    body += inputLine;
                }
                System.out.println(body);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

the error in Java 6 : **sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target**

Somebody know how it's different ? Can I use some tricks to have the same result in Java 6 ?

The CN of the cert is a wildcard : "*.domain.com" . It can be the cause ?

I tried several api but there all used the sun SSL layer. Do you know an other to replace it ?

Comment: follow the link Step by Step :
http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target/

Comment: Just one of many reasons NOT to use Java 6 anymore.  The last public release of Java 6 was 7 years ago.

Comment: I'm agree with you, but have I not the choice of the java version on the project.

Answer (score 0):

JRE has it's own keystore, [where certificates can be stored](https://www.benecke.cloud/java-runtime-environment-jre-how-to-import-certificates/). Maybe your JDK/JRE for Java 6 has different keys than Java 8.

Comment: I use the **-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore** to definie the same custom trustore

Comment: In debug mode I see the all chain's certificate loaded.